# Access different views inside of a UITableViewCell by tag in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to make an app for iOS 8, using swift. The goal here is to make a kind of news feed. This feed displays posts from users, which follows a certain pattern.

I thought of using the UITableView where each cell follows a custom layout. The problem appears when I try to access a text label inside it. I try to access it by its tag, but when I do it, the whole app crashes. The error reported is `"Swift dynamic cast failed"`, and I'm using the following code to access the view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cellId: String = "cell"

    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath{
        cell.textLabel.text = myData[ip.row] as String
        var lbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(0) as UILabel
        lbl.text = "ola"
    }

    return cell
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see the code where you are actually setting the tag.

Comment: I have already tried to use other values for tags, but still the same thing happens

Comment: @Avismara I'm doing it in the interface builder... Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No thats fine. You could set your tag value in IB too.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cell.viewWithTag(0)` instead of `cell.contentView.viewWithTag(0)` ?

Comment: You are using not a custom cell here? Where do you add your label to your view?

Comment: No, i use cell.contentView.viewWithTag(...) too. That works fine.

Comment: Why do you want to get the view this way? Set the `UILabel` as a property. And get that view by saying something like `cell.label`? This isn't answer, but just a better approach, IMO.

Comment: @Avismara You made me think twice and you're right.. I'll follow that approach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i think the Problem is the Tag 0. All Views are on default value 0. So try another tag value.

Comment: i which line is the problem:  var lbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(0) as UILabel? Did you set the correct tag in IB?

Comment: I guess the Problem here is that you are using a basic? cell Layout. How do you add the second label? Do you have any code here?

Comment: I duplicated the crash and fixed it with this answer, once I changed the tag to a non zero number everything worked for me.

Comment: It's not my question otherwise I would. I was just seeing if I could come up with a different answer but after duplicating it I came up with the same answer as you @derdida

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same issue. The solution was to change tag to 10 and 20. I used 1 and 2 before. Is anybody aware of a range of tags that is used by the system?

So my 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' for a table with an image and a label per row looks like this now:

```
internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell {
        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(10) as UIImageView).image = IMAGES[indexPath.row]
        (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(20) as UILabel).text = LABELS[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    } else {
        NSLog("Prototype did not work")
        return UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "errorIdentifier")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes same issue faced here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 0 to 1 or another tag, it work for me.

0 is overlapping to another cell label's tag.